# request.form() throws 'undefined is not a function' error in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, email-attachments, request.form

I want to create a form on a `request` in Node to add attachments to an email. As far as I can tell [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms) under the multipart/form-data (Multipart Form Uploads) section I should be able to create a request form using

`var r = request.form()`

But I am getting this error in the console.

```
var fd = request.form();
                          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Looking at the linked documentation, and on the advice of Chris G below, again I changed my code to look like this:

```
     var r = request.post(reqOptions, function (err, resp) {
        //console.log(resp.body);
        //console.log(resp.statusCode);   
        if (err) {
          return deferred.reject({
              code: _.get(resp, 'statusCode'),
              reason: err.message || err.errmsg
          });
        } ...
      );
      var form = r.form();
      form.append('attachmentA',fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'abc.jpg')));
```

Now I get the following error.

```
{ code: undefined, reason: 'write after end' }
```

Comment: `.form()` can only be called on `request.post(...)`, not `request` itself.

Comment: How might I do that with `request.post(reqOptions, function (err, resp) { if(err) ...console.log(resp) }` . How can form-data be added after the post is made? Thanks for the response.

Comment: In the example code you linked to, using `.form()` is done after `.post()` is called with only a single argument. I assume in that case the request isn't made until you call `form.submit()`. See here: https://github.com/form-data/form-data

Comment: Oh I missed that. Thanks for pointing out. I did this `var r = request.post(...); var form = r.form();
      form.append('attachmentA', fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'abc.jpg')));` but I'm getting a `{ code: undefined, reason: 'write after end' }`. It sounds like it's saying it can "write" to the post because it's finished. Any idea what's wrong?